# How to have a reference of child elements of a component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to have a reference of child elements of a component in that component.
I have tried both ElementRef, TemplateRef and QueryList with ViewChild, ViewChildren, ContentChild, ContentChildren but no luck.

```html
<app-modal>
   <section #reference>
    <h1>I NEED THIS ELEMENT</h1>
   </section>
</app-modal>
```

I want complete reference of `section` element along with its children as html elements.

```js
@ViewChild('reference') ref: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.ref.nativeElement);  -----> logged TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
}

ngAfterContentInit(){
  console.log(this.ref.nativeElement); -----> logged TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
}
```

so that I can send the same ref to another component and display as innerHTML in dev.

```html
<div innerHTML='ref'></div>
```

Your quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Its a typo, I corrected it. I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')`

Comment: Please check the complete code here... https://dev.to/rammurthykota/viewchild-viewchildren-and-contentchild-contentchildren-are-undefined-in-angular-material-dialog-1c7k

Comment: Are you sure this isn't because of the typo in "text'... <app-modal [title]="title" [btnText]="text'>

Comment: Did you check the compilation errors.

Comment: Try `ViewChild('reference', {static: true}) ref: ElementRef;
` and access ref property in `ngOnInit` method

Comment: `@ContentChild('reference', {static: true}) ref: ElementRef;` worked for me in `ngAfterContentInit`, but when I'm trying to do `<div innerHTML="ref"></div>` in another component, it is showing `[object HTMLElement]`

Comment: If you could share a full picture of what you are doing maybe you would get a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could use:

```
<div [innerHTML]="ref.outerHTML"></div>
```

However, more regular way would be (assuming that you want to use the HTML in your `app-modal`):

```
<app-modal>
  <section name="reference">
```

Then inject it in the template of app modal:

```
<ng-content select="section[name=reference]"></ng-content>
```